# Library for complex numbers in Dev-C++

Tags: dev-c++

What is the library for complex numbers in Dev-C++ (version 5.11)?
I tried to use

```
#include <complex.h>
```

but it doesn't work:

```
39  2   C:\Users\Àíòîí\Documents\DevCC_Projects\fourier\main.cpp    [Error] 'complex' was not declared in this scope
```

So I cannot use functions like

```
.real
```

What is an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The complex class is c++ and is in the complex header. Use instead:

```
#include <complex>
```

Documentation for the class can be found in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement one? It is not that hard. Basically you need a class `Complex`, which will have two members, `r` and `i`, you need to override a few operators, like:

`+`: `(a + b).r === a.r + b.r`, `(a + b).i === (a.i + b.i)`

`-`: `(a - b).r === a.r - b.r`, `(a - b).i === (a.i - b.i)`

`*`: `(a * b).r === a.r * b.r - (a.i * b.i)`, `(a * b).r === a.r * b.i + a.i * b.r`

`/`: `(a / b).r === a.r * b.r - (a.i * b.i)`, `(a / b).i (a.r * b.i + a.i * b.r)`

Make sure that you handle the special case of division by 0. Also, you might implement `++`, `--`, `<<`, `>>` and so on, according to your taste.